# Firefoxにおける大量のPostリクエスト処理で出るエラーについて On errors occurred in large amount of Post request processing in Firefox

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, firefox, axios

現在Vue.jsを使用してアプリケーションを作成しております。

その中でaxiosを使用しAPIでクライアント側から画像をアップロードしてサーバー側にて画像に加工を行いその加工した画像をレスポンスで受けるという仕組みを作成致しました。

その処理を非同期で行うと処理は高速化したのですがFirefoxの場合のみ大量に画像をアップロードすると10画像程度でレスポンスを受けられなくなるという現象が発生しております。

chrome等他のブラウザでは発生しません。

コンソールでは特にエラーが出ていないのですがこの現象を回避する方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃるでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します

We are currently using Vue.js to create applications.

Among them, we created a mechanism that uses axios to upload images from the client side via API, processing on images on the server side, and receiving the processed images with responses.

Processing speeded up when doing that processing asynchronously, but in the case of Firefox only when uploading a large number of images uploading images can not receive responses in about 10 images has occurred.

It does not occur in other browsers such as chrome.

There are no particular errors on the console, but do you know how to avoid this phenomenon?

Comment: この問題は自己解決しました！ありがとうございました！
This problem is already been cleared up. thank you!

Comment: 自己解決した場合は、自分自身で回答を書き、その回答を承認して下さい。詳しくは[「自分の質問に回答できますか?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)をご覧下さい。ちなみに、このサイト ([**ja**.stackoverflow.com](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)) は Stack Overflow ([stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/)) とは独立して日本語の質問を扱うサイトとして運営されています。詳しくは、[Can I ask questions in English? / 英語で質問してもいいですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314/3054) をご覧ください。つまり、このサイトへの投稿は日本語話者にしかリーチしませんので、英訳を付ける必要はありません。英語で広く回答を募りたい場合は、[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) へ英語の質問を投稿する必要があります。

Comment: 了解しました。対策としては一度のPost最大リクエスト数を6とすることで解決出来ました